# The meaning of "strewn" in this context

Tags: meaning

> The bodies of inmates, who died of disease and starvation, were **strewn** about the camp and filled the barracks, and the British forces compelled the S.S. officers who ran the camp to bury them in mass graves—and ordered local notables to watch the burials take place. [Source](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/movies/2014/01/hitchcock-and-the-holocaust.html)

In this case, *strewn* can be interpreted as a state, not an action by someone. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct; the condition of the bodies was that they were "strewn about the camp", that is, they could be found in various locations looking as if they had been tossed there casually and randomly, with no concern for placement or appearance.

Comment: But in other contexts, it can mean "action" like, "The body was strewn on the road by this brutal man."? The conclusion is whether it's an action or condition depends on the context?